# Grails Map domain class column name problems

Tags: grails

I have a MS SQL DB (which I can't change) with 3 tables :

```
contact  
id, name, number
```

```
c_group  
id,name,email
```

```
contact_group  
id, contact_id, group_id
```

In Grails I have 3 domain classes :

```
class Cgroup {  
    String name
    String email

    static constraints = {
    }

    static mapping = {
        table name: "c_group"
        version false
    }   
}
```

```
class Contact {
    String name
    String number

    static constraints = {
        name nullable:false
    }

    static mapping = {
        version false
    }
}
```

```
class Contact_group {
    Cgroup cgroup
    Contact contact

    static constraints = {
    }

    static mapping = {
        version false
        cgroup_id column: "c_group_id", sqlType: "int" 
    }
}
```

I'm trying to create a list using :-

```
def contactInstance = Contact.get(id)  //I have previously got the id

List userGroupList = Contact_group.createCriteria().list(params) {            
    eq("contact", contactInstance)
}
```

And it is throwing an error

> Invalid column name 'cgroup_id'.. Stacktrace follows:

As you can see, I'm trying to map the correct column name (in the `Contact_group` domain class) as the table has been renamed from `group` to `c_group` in the DB, and just to complicate matters for some reason I decided to call the domain class `Cgroup` in my Grails app. (I can change this if needs be)

So, I'm now in a bit of a muddle about how best to create the list. Any suggestions or pointers?

Comment: UPDATE:  To try to keep things as straightforward as possible I have renamed the Cgroup domain class to C_group, so it now mpas directly to the table name. And of course I have removed the :-   table name: "c_group"  line

Comment: You should add updates to your question by using the [edit] button. Anyway: I would really discourage you to use names like that. You are better off using a common naming convention. (Not only for classes but for names in general.) It is way better for the readability.

Answer (score 2):

In your mapping you should point to the class property (`cgroup_id` should be `cgroup`, since that is what you named it in your domain.)

Also, your column name in your table is `id` not `c_group_id` so you should set the column as `id`.

```
static mapping = {
    version false
    table name: "contact_group"
    cgroup column: "id", sqlType: "int"        
}
```

Comment: That still throws an error. (Note my update above re changing the Cgroup domain name).  I added the line  c_group column: "c_group_id", sqlType: "int"   and it still throws an error - Invalid column name 'c_group_id'.. Stacktrace follows:

Comment: But what DID work was adding the line :-  c_group column: "group_id", sqlType: "int"        Many thanks for getting me looking in the right direction. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Simon As i mentioned in my comment on your question, you should not use a class/domain name like `C_group` rather add `table name: "c_group"` to your mapping.

Comment: Point taken, and thanks very much for your assistance. Like I said, I'm very much a newbie, and every day is a learning day!  So I do appreciate your guidance.